# Android Icon notifications, wrong drawable

Tags: android, push-notification, icons

I'm notifying the user of some events via Firebase and setting dynamically a small Icon with NotificationBuilder:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.orangeMain))
                    .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
                    .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                  .setSound( Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                           + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/coins")) //raw/name of the mp3
                    .setContentText(notificationText)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{0,1000}) //vibration in ms
                  //  .setLights(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.orangeMain),500,500) //led color, ms On, ms Off
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
```

The smallIcon int is the drawable id, like R.drawable.ic_my_image, but passed after if-else statements, in such a way to customize the icon.

The problem is that the icon that is displayed seems to be chosen randomly between all the drawables that I've stored in the drawable folder. The drawables are bot svg (xml in the folder) and png. What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: to retrieve the drawables I'm using a function like this:

```
 int smallIcon = retrieveSmallIcon(abbreviation);

public static int retrieveSmallIcon(String abbreviation){

    int smallIcon;
    if(abbreviation.toLowerCase().equals("BTC".toLowerCase())) {
        smallIcon = R.drawable.ic_coin_symbol_bitcoin;
    }
    else if (abbreviation.toLowerCase().equals("XMR".toLowerCase())){
        smallIcon = R.drawable.ic_xmr;
    }
    else if (abbreviation.toLowerCase().equals("ETH".toLowerCase())){
        smallIcon = R.drawable.ic_eth;
    }
    else if (abbreviation.toLowerCase().equals("DASH".toLowerCase())){
        smallIcon = R.drawable.ic_dash_alt;
    }
    else if (abbreviation.toLowerCase().equals("LTC".toLowerCase())){
        smallIcon = R.drawable.ic_ltc_alt;
    }
    else if (abbreviation.toLowerCase().equals("XRP".toLowerCase())){
        smallIcon = R.drawable.ic_xrp_alt;
    }
    else if (abbreviation.toLowerCase().equals("ETC".toLowerCase())){
        smallIcon = R.drawable.ic_etc_alt;
    }
    else {
        smallIcon = CoinsUtils.NOT_FOUND_ICON;
    }

    return  smallIcon;
}
```